# After Logout, Login page doesn't open

Tags: spring, redirect, extjs, spring-security, logout

Because of some reasons I have a spring application which has two client applications written in extjs. One only contains the login page and the other the application logic. In Spring I include them into two jsp pages which I'm using in the controller.

The login and the redirect to the application page works fine. But if I logout the logout is done successful but I keep staying on the application page instead of being redirected to the login page.

security config:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/main/logoutpage.html" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/test/logout.html"/>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/logout.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView testLogout(@RequestParam(required=false)Integer error, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

"login" is the name of the view which contains the login application. In browser debugging I can see following two communcation:

```
    Request URL:http://xx:8080/xx/xx/logoutpage.html?_dc=1358246248972
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=6E22E42CC6835C8A6DFF2535907DEF17
Host:xx:8080
Referer:http://xx:8080/xx/xx/Home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
_dc:1358246248972
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 15 Jan 2013 10:37:33 GMT
Location:http://xx:8080/xx/xx/login.html
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/xx



Request URL:http://xx:8080/xx/xx/login.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=6E22E42CC6835C8A6DFF2535907DEF17
Host:xx:8080
Referer:http://xx:8080/xx/xx/Home.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Content-Language:de-DE
Content-Length:417
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue, 15 Jan 2013 10:37:33 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=532EBEED737BD4172E290F0D10085ED5; Path=/xx/; HttpOnly
```

The second response also contains the login page:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/xx/main/app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Somebody has an idea why the login page is not shown?

Thanks

Comment: do you not being redirected to logout-success-url="/test/logout.html"?

Comment: What do you mean: "I keep staying on the application page"? Do you call the logout via AJAX? Or after logout you browser was redirected to application page?

Comment: @OhadR : In my client I do the following AJAX call: Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : '/xx/main/logoutpage.html',
    timeout : '30000',
}); The controller is also reacting and is returning the "login" view

Comment: @Maksym Demidas: When I'm on my "homepage" I'm clicking on logout. The only thing I see on server side that the logout is done successful and the "login" view is returned by the controller. But in my browser window the "homepage" is still shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of custom JavaScript handler for logout control just use a normal link:

```
<a href="/main/logoutpage.html">Logout</a>
```

Logout controller uses **HTTP redirect** to show login page. In a case of AJAX call redirect does not work like you want. Look into XmlHttpResponse of your AJAX call. You will find the logout page there.

Comment: I think you mean href="/main/logoutpage.html". That's right. But it will cause the same actions on server side ending in no redirection to the login page I think, or?

Comment: It will cause a redirect after logout due to logout-success-url="/test/logout.html"

Comment: Yes right. But that is again only a request for the controller I defined on top. And he will return the "login" view.

Comment: Actually redirect is working fine. The problem is that it is not shown in your browser because it is executed via AJAX call. It is "present" in the result of AJAX call.

Comment: Yes right. I do it in the same way for the login. I do a form submit for the login url I defined in the security of spring. Then I have a controller action for catching the redirecting url and returning the "homepage" view. So, maybe it is not the same. Because for login I'm doing a form submit ;-) Hmm, so you think the link href="/main/logoutpage.html" will result in another behaviour? Or can I trigger the redirect in another way?

Comment: Yes. Try it. I think it helps.

Comment: So at the moment I have a menu item which and a controller for it. So the new solution should look like that one. Any idea? I'm totally new to Spring, to extjs and also in general in javascript and had to replace the GUI of an existing application which was realized with flex. So sorry for asking newbie questions ;-)

Comment: document.location.href = '/xx/main/logoutpage.html'; works :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "One only contains the login page and the other the application logic"? you have 2 apps? 2 different WARs/JARs?

please explain...

BTW - After logout, you want to redirect the user to a *protected resource* in your app, and then **Spring** will redirect the user to the login page. You do not have to (or should not) implicitly redirect to the login page by yourself.

Comment: I have two extjs applications embedded in two different jsp pages. So the fist one is started when someone opens /login.html. The second one is started after login when a controller returns the view with the jsp page which is containing the second extjs application. Because of that, after logout, I have to do a redirect to the view which with the jsp page which is containing the extjs app for the login.